# Inline Edit pencil in Lightning Datatable causes redirect (instead of editable cell)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

In my project I have a child component which displays a lightning-datatable.

```
<c-editor-step-datatable key={item.path} table-data={item.table.data} table-columns={item.table.columns}></c-editor-step-datatable>
```

The datatable is displayed correctly, with inline edit enabled.
However, as soon as an Inline Edit button is clicked, the page is refreshed!
There are no custom events attached and I can't figure out why the refresh occurs.

Clicking on the button in the green circle will correctly activate inline edit on a field
Clicking on any of the pencils (in the red circles) will trigger a redirect!!
[image: Modal component with datatable child component]

The initial page URL is ".../lightning/n/MainPageURL"
The redirect is performed to ".../lightning/n/MainPageURL?"

This behaviour does not occur when using the "openInlineEdit" event on the datatable.
However, using "openInlineEdit" is not desired as it more cumbersome for users.

```
this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').openInlineEdit();
```

**Javascript:**

```
...
_data;
_columns;
_keyField;

@api
get tableData() {
    return this._data;
}
set tableData(value) {
    if(value)
        this._data = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( value ) );
}

@api
get tableColumns() {
    return this._columns;
}
set tableColumns(value) {
    if(value) {
        this._keyField = value[0].fieldName;
        this._columns = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( value ) );
        this._columns.push({type: "button-icon", typeAttributes: {iconName: "utility:edit", name: "edit"}, fixedWidth: 40});
        this._columns.push({type: "button-icon", typeAttributes: {iconName: "utility:delete", name: "delete", iconClass: "slds-icon-text-error"}, fixedWidth: 40});
    }
}
...
```

**Template:**

```
...
<lightning-datatable
    data={_data}
    columns={_columns}
    key-field={_keyField}
    hide-checkbox-column
></lightning-datatable>
...
```

**Contents:**
Below are the values of:
_keyField
_columns
_data
[image: Property contents]

Why does the inline edit pencil trigger a redirect?
How can this behaviour be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using lightning datatable inside lightning-record-edit-form (lightning data service) so it is redirecting. If you would move your datatable code out of the lightning record form it would work fine.

Thanks!!